# How to setup a loopback audio device on startup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, startup

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 x64.

I want to create a virtual audio device and connect it to a real speaker when the OS starts up.

I've confirmed these operations by entering the following commands to the terminal(*Device names are some omitted):

> sudo modprobe snd-aloop pcm_substreams=2
>
> pactl load-module module-loopback source=alsa_output.platform-snd_aloop sink=alsa_output.pci

I wrote them in "/etc/rc.local" and "/etc/pulse/default.pa" but it didn't work.

Please tell me target files for startup setting and the correct text.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using systemd and the sound.target, which should execute your commands after the sound system becomes available.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-targets

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would appreciate it if you could give me specific examples such as what kind of text file to create and where to put it.